# Computing how many distinct digital products are below $10^n$

Tags: combinatorics, recursive-algorithms, inclusion-exclusion

Given a number $n$, its digital product is the product of its digit. So the digital product of $15$ is $1\times 5=5$, and the digital product of $760$ is $0$, etc.

I recently saw a nice video on Numberphile where they discussed persistence, namely how many iterations of digital product do you need in order to reach a single digit (e.g. $75\to 35\to 15\to 5$ has persistence of $3$).

Playing a bit with the idea, it occurred to me that an efficient way of writing a code to check for this would include having a dictionary. This is because if I know that $35$ requires two steps, I don't need to iterate three steps from $75$, I can just notice that it's one more than $35$.

Of course, you don't want to store this information for every number, because then you'd be wasting *a lot* of memory when testing this with very large numbers.

So my first quest was to wonder what would be the maximal size of a dictionary we need. Well, If we test all the way to $10^n$, the largest digital product would be $10^n-1$, which is $9^n$. This is great, since $\frac{9^n}{10^n}\to 0$, so you're being relatively efficient. But in the real world, this is still a massive size of memory allocation on a personal computer.

The next step, therefore, is to ask, **how many distinct values can we get from a digital product**?

I tested this up to $10^8$, and the answer may surprise you. It turns out that there are only $2026$ values that you get from digital products below $10^8$. About half of those are actually $0$, since the longer the number the harder it is to avoid $0$, but we are still talking about $43000000$ numbers whose product is non-zero.

Here is a basic state of the results:

$$\begin{array}{c|l}
\text{Below} & \text{Distinct digital products}\\\hline
10^0 & 1\\
10^1 & 10\\
10^2 & 37\\
10^3 & 101\\ 
10^4 & 226\\
10^5 & 442\\
10^6 & 785\\
10^7 & 1297\\
10^8 & 2026
\end{array}$$

This is quite a slow growth rate, and again, it makes sense. The longer your numbers are, the more likely they are to have $0$ inside, and if not a $0$, then at least $1$ which can then be omitted and not change the value of the product.

Obviously, the first question is whether or not there are only finitely many digital products. Of course not. $10^n-1$ has a digital product of $9^{n-1}$, which would provide us with infinitely many distinct values.

> Is there a relatively straightforward to recursively compute how many distinct digital products are there below $10^n$? Or at least a reasonable upper bound?

(Note that there is some intuition as to why this can be done recursively. For example, if $k$ has small digits ($1$ to $4$, then $10k+2$ has the same digital product as $2k$, so if $2$ appears in a number of length $n$, and all the digits are small, it does not add a new value. There are a lot of cases to test, and , which is why I hope someone more talented than me when it comes to finite combinatorics can see through them.)

Comment: It is a long story till we get the question, please fix the subject of the question (is there... what... to compute?!) Do we compute using a computer? Do we need to compute this for $n$ (from "below $10^n$") up to $n=10$, or $n=20$, or $n=100$... ? (This kind of "finite ergodic game" is a nice game, but we cannot expect structure or mathematical insight. So let us get the pragmatic view in detail...)

Comment: Yes, it's a long story. I'm also not sure what's unclear. I don't **need** to compute anything. I am curious about the existence of a straightforward way of doing that which doesn't involve bruteforce approach. I'd be happy to hear about heuristics within "feasible ranges" (e.g. below $10^{1000}$) and I'd also be happy to hear a general proof.

Comment: Second generation products need either no even digits or no $5$s in the original number, which puts an upper bound of $O(n^3)$ in the second-generation products

Comment: @Empy2: I realized earlier today that actually once can do this recursively in $O(n^2)$, or probably $n\log n$ or so. Start with $D_0=\{1\}$, then let $D_{n+1}$ be $\{d\cdot k\mid d\in\{0,\dots,9\}, k\in D_n\}$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila - How would that be $O(n^2)$?  The set operations themselves may look like primitives $O(1)$ but in reality they are not.  In any case $|D_n| = O(n^4)$ so you cannot compute it in $O(n^2)$, right?

Comment: @antkam: How do you figure $n^4$? Your $D_{n+1}$ is just $10$ things added for each member of $D_n$. So I'm not sure what you mean by "look like primitives but in reality they are not".

Comment: oh, sorry, perhaps I totally misunderstood you.  I thought $D_n$ is supposed to be the set of all DPs below $10^n$.  As the answers by Oldboy & Empy2 have shown, the no. of elements $|D_n|$ grows as $n^4$.

Comment: @antkam: Well, my suggestion was a recursive algorithm, so to get $D_n$ you'd need to run it $n$ times, which is where the extra $n^2$ comes from, I guess. I meant that the recursion *step* is at $O(n^2)$, which may or may not be a mistake on my part as well.

Comment: Your algo is the same as Oldboy's old java code (I think... but I am not a java expert).  Indeed the main function (his getUniqueProducts) is called $n$ times, but the running time for each call is different (at least, in the non-parallel version) -- there are $10 |D_n|$ multiplications and set-insertions, and each set-insertion is itself not a constant (primitive/atomic) operation.

Comment: @antkam: It is if you're thinking about it in abstract terms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is basically [OEIS sequence A154323](https://oeis.org/A154323) representing central coefficients of number triangle [A113582](https://oeis.org/A113582). The OEIS page gives the following formula:

> $$a_n = \frac{n^4 + 2n^3 + n^2 + 4}4=1+\binom{n+1}{2}^2$$

The is actually the formula provided by Empty2, just with a different starting index ($n$ instead of $n+1$).

Even without a closed form solution, you can count the number of distinct products with just a few lines of code. I have decided to choose Java because since Java8 it's very easy to employ all existing CPU cores in stream-based computations which shortens computation times significantly.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Application {
    public static final int N = 100;

    static Set<BigInteger> getUniqueProducts(int generation) {
        Set<BigInteger> result = new HashSet<>();
        if(generation == 0) {
            result.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        }
        else {
            Set<BigInteger> products = getUniqueProducts(generation - 1);
            result = products.stream().parallel().flatMap(
                    product -> IntStream
                        .range(0, 10)
                        .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                        .map(s -> new BigInteger(s))
                        .map(num -> num.multiply(product))
            ).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        }
        System.out.println("10^{" + generation + "} & " + result.size() + "\\\\");
        return result;
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("\\begin{array}{c|l}");
        System.out.println("\\text{Below} & \\text{Distinct digital products}\\\\\\hline");
        getUniqueProducts(N);
        System.out.println("\\end{array}");
    }
}
```

Here are the results up to $n=80$:

$$\begin{array}{c|l}
\text{Below} & \text{Distinct digital products}\\\hline
10^{0} & 1\\
10^{1} & 10\\
10^{2} & 37\\
10^{3} & 101\\
10^{4} & 226\\
10^{5} & 442\\
10^{6} & 785\\
10^{7} & 1297\\
10^{8} & 2026\\
10^{9} & 3026\\
10^{10} & 4357\\
10^{11} & 6085\\
10^{12} & 8282\\
10^{13} & 11026\\
10^{14} & 14401\\
10^{15} & 18497\\
10^{16} & 23410\\
10^{17} & 29242\\
10^{18} & 36101\\
10^{19} & 44101\\
10^{20} & 53362\\
10^{21} & 64010\\
10^{22} & 76177\\
10^{23} & 90001\\
10^{24} & 105626\\
10^{25} & 123202\\
10^{26} & 142885\\
10^{27} & 164837\\
10^{28} & 189226\\
10^{29} & 216226\\
10^{30} & 246017\\
10^{31} & 278785\\
10^{32} & 314722\\
10^{33} & 354026\\
10^{34} & 396901\\
10^{35} & 443557\\
10^{36} & 494210\\
10^{37} & 549082\\
10^{38} & 608401\\
10^{39} & 672401\\
10^{40} & 741322\\
10^{41} & 815410\\
10^{42} & 894917\\
10^{43} & 980101\\
10^{44} & 1071226\\
10^{45} & 1168562\\
10^{46} & 1272385\\
10^{47} & 1382977\\
10^{48} & 1500626\\
10^{49} & 1625626\\
10^{50} & 1758277\\
10^{51} & 1898885\\
10^{52} & 2047762\\
10^{53} & 2205226\\
10^{54} & 2371601\\
10^{55} & 2547217\\
10^{56} & 2732410\\
10^{57} & 2927522\\
10^{58} & 3132901\\
10^{59} & 3348901\\
10^{60} & 3575882\\
10^{61} & 3814210\\
10^{62} & 4064257\\
10^{63} & 4326401\\
10^{64} & 4601026\\
10^{65} & 4888522\\
10^{66} & 5189285\\
10^{67} & 5503717\\
10^{68} & 5832226\\
10^{69} & 6175226\\
10^{70} & 6533137\\
10^{71} & 6906385\\
10^{72} & 7295402\\
10^{73} & 7700626\\
10^{74} & 8122501\\
10^{75} & 8561477\\
10^{76} & 9018010\\
10^{77} & 9492562\\
10^{78} & 9985601\\
10^{79} & 10497601\\
10^{80} & 11029042\\
\end{array}$$

...and a chart:

[image]

...also using logarithmic scaling:

[image]

Comment: I'm confused about your formula, since it does not fit with the one by Empy2. (Also, Java? Ew. :-))

Comment: @AsafKaragila It's actually the same formula, just check the introdcutory part of my answer again. I have changed it a little bit. Regarding Java... What's wrong with it? :) I did not have Mathematica handy. With streams and lambda functions  introduced in Java8, it's easy to use all your CPUs to speed up computations significantly. I see that people prefer Python which I find inferior (terrible execution speeds, limited multithreading capabilities). My language of choice is actually Scala (Java on steroids) but it has much smaller user base. I can also do C++ and Go so by my guest :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I forgot to metion PHP :)))))))))

Comment: If you want true speed, then it's assembler or nothing. If you want elegance, then go (Common) Lisp or go home. With lambda functions introduced in 1958...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Writing a complex multi-threaded application in assembler is a challenge of epic proportions. Life is often too short for that. Speaking of elegance, it's often influenced by personal feelings, tastes, or opinions. ((Lisp)) is somewhere near the end of my list but it can be at the top of yours. But the fact is: Lisp never took off and here is an interesting discussion about that: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/60012/why-isnt-lisp-more-widespread

Comment: Frankly those reasons given in that thread sound more like the reasons why set theory is not more widespread. It wasn't until now, and people tend to keep with convention (which is why we keep hearing for the past 50 years that within a few years nobody will be doing set theory no more). Those are valid reasons to some extent, but they are all a postriori and not a priori reasons for lisp not taking off. As for the assembler, I beg to differ. And I also think that if you don't know any Java, then learning enough of it to be able to write your code on your own is also an epic challenge...

Comment: @AsafKaragila With due respect, I disagree. If you don't know anything about assembler and you don't know anything about Java, you will always learn how to do something in Java faster. You can learn to write a program that sorts an array of integers in Java in 10 minutes. And in assembler? On the other side, posting a Lisp program here is like writing an answer in a language than only a few people speak. It could be the most elegant language in the world, but it does not matter. English is the most popular language in the world and elegance has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Maybe it's because I have been working with assembler (on and off, since I'm not a professional programmer) for the better part of 20 years. Who knows. If English is the most popular language in the world ([which could be contested](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers)), why did you even write code in your answer? Why not an English-based pseudocode? By the way, syntactic analysis was done and it showed that English is rather simplified in many ways and serves as a very good lingua franca, so elegance *does* have something to do with that... :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila In my native language, each letter is always pronounced in the same way, it does not matter where it stands in the word, which letter comes next or stands in front of it. Ther are no exceptions. So I can teach you to write and read my language perfectly with zero mistakes in about 5 minutes. That's elegance :) Anyway, my native language is disappearing quickly.

Comment: @Oldboy - while I agree with your points re: programming language, I found it funny (ironic?) that you write in java to INCREASE the set of people who can understand your code, BUT your parallelized version might have severely REDUCED that set!  Indeed, I could understand your original code but I no longer understand this new parallelized version.  :)

Comment: @antkam +1. You are right, now I regret (and apologize for) that. I have sacrificed clarity for performance and that was not the right thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

The product is $2^a3^b5^c7^d$ where $a/3+b/2+c+d\le n$, with an adjustment for 6s, so what is the volume of a four-dimensional simplex?
Except for $n=0$, the numbers in @Oldboy's answer follow $$1+{n+2\choose 2}^2$$
I don't know why.

Comment: +1 very nice!  what adjustment for $6$s do you have in mind?

Comment: $6^2$ could be replaced by $4×9$ so I only have to worry about one $6$

Comment: But why worry about one $6$?  e.g. in the number $6555$ for $n=4$, you have $a=b=1, c=3$ and that still satisfies $a/3 + b/2 + c + d \le n$.  Nowhere did you say $a/3$ and $b/2$ have to be integers.

Comment: How did you get from the inequality $a/3+b/2+c+d\le n$ to the closed-form expression $1+{n+2\choose 2}^2$?  Can you elaborate on the math techniques involved?

Comment: You've caught me out - I just used Oldboy's results, and found all the differences of the differences of the differences of the differences were the same.

Comment: hahahaha, that is the most fun math-related sentence I've read in a while!  diff(diff(diff(diff(array)))) = constant!  next time i need to say blah is a polynomial of degree $k,$ I will say it this way instead.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

A loose upperbound (and possible approach for exact count?)

Lets say a number $< 10^n$ has $n$ digits, including possibly leading $0$s.  If any digit is $0$ then the DP is $0$.  Ignoring those, we have $n$ digits which are $1-9$.  The ordering of the digits don't matter, so we're really just interested in the multiset of digits (multiset because the number of times e.g. $5$ appears matters).

To count such multisets, we can throw $n$ balls into nine boxes.  The number of ways, by stars and bars method, is ${n+8 \choose 8}$.  So this is an upperbound.  E.g. for $n=4,5,6,7,8$ the upperbounds are $495, 1287, 3003,6435,12870$ respectively.

The reason this is not tight is because e.g. $2\times 3 = 1 \times 6$, etc.  If there is a way to account for all such equivalences then we'd have a formula for the exact count.

Comment: I was just confused.  Sorry.  It would be easy to count if different multisets gave different products.  You have noted one case where that doesn't happen.  There are a number of others.  You are correct that you give an upper bound.  I think it is hard to enumerate the cases where different multisets give the same product.

Comment: @RossMillikan - I was only halfway into my morning coffee at the time, and feeling unsure myself, so I can fully sympathize.  :)